# What buffers to use for receiving an input stream from a Socket created by ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, buffer

One way to receive string input from a server socket and outputting it would be this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {


        Socket clientSocket;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8878);
        try {
            while((clientSocket = server.accept()) != null) {
                InputStream stream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String nextLine = reader.readLine();
                if(nextLine != null) {
                    System.out.println(nextLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

 }
```

However, the `InputStream` could be replaced by a `BufferedInputStream`

Would this result in a sort of a 'double buffer', where a buffered reader reads from an already-buffered input stream?

Also, one could read with an input stream reader (without buffered reader) and still have a buffered input stream.

I'm just confused as to which implementation would be most efficient (after all, the whole point of any buffer is increased efficiency?).

My main priority is to not let any of the bytes coming though the `clientSocket` input stream get lost. After that it's all about efficiency. Does that effect which combination of buffers I should choose?

Please let me know  **In what places of the code above would you use a buffer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this result in a sort of a 'double buffer', where a buffered reader reads from an already-buffered input stream?

No.

> Also, one could read with an input stream reader (without buffered reader) and still have a buffered input stream.

Meaningless.

> I'm just confused as to which implementation would be most efficient (after all, the whole point of any buffer is increased efficiency?).

Meaningless. What exactly are you talking about with these last two questions?

> My main priority is to not let any of the bytes coming though the clientSocket input stream get lost.

Then you fail, because you're only reading one line from the socket. If you want to read it all, *assuming* that the data is lines:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

> After that it's all about efficiency. Does that effect which combination of buffers I should choose?

Again this question is meaningless without examples of what you're talking about.

NB

```
while((clientSocket = server.accept()) != null)
```

is meaningless. `ServerSocket.accept()` cannot return null. Therefore testing for it is futile.

Comment: Thanks, was great help